# Counting flops in VGGNET vs ResNet

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network, resnet, vgg-net

I would like to know how a 16 layer VGGNET has 15.3 billion flops while 152 layer Resnet has only 11.3 billion flops. Is it because of the initial layers of VGGNet which run 64 filters on the 224x224 image?

Comment: Check [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/280338) it may answer your question.

Comment: I have already checked it and is answers my question only partially. In fact I have put a comment there